3ware LSI RAID Controller not recognized by tw_cli utility
I am attempting to resolve an issue regarding the raid controller on my server. What I am trying to resolve is the following error message when I use the tw_cli utility.
tw_cli > show

No controller found.
Make sure appropriate LSI/3ware device driver(s) are loaded.

Hardware + Software Specifications
----------
$ lspci | grep 3w
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: 3ware Inc 9750 SAS2/SATA-II RAID PCIe (rev 05)
----------
$ uname -r
4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64

I have gone through the following troubleshooting steps:

Update the firmware on the controller to what is found within the following:
3ware 10.2.2.1 Complete Codeset (ISO download link).

Update the controller driver to: kmod-3w-9xxx-2.26.02.014-11.el8_9.elrepo.x86_64.rpm.
I do not receive any output for the command: $ dmesg | grep 3w, however I do for this:


$ find /lib/modules | grep 3w
/lib/modules/4.18.0-372.9.1.el8.x86_64/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-x86_64-3way.ko.xz
/lib/modules/4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-x86_64-3way.ko.xz
/lib/modules/4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64/kernel/drivers/kmod-3w-9xxx-2.26.02.014-11.el8_9.elrepo.x86_64.rpm
/lib/modules/4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64/kmod-3w-9xxx-2.26.02.014-11.el8_9.elrepo.x86_64.rpm
/lib/modules/4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64/weak-updates/3w-9xxx
/lib/modules/4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64/weak-updates/3w-9xxx/3w-9xxx.ko
/lib/modules/4.18.0-513.5.1.el8_9.x86_64/extra/3w-9xxx
/lib/modules/4.18.0-513.5.1.el8_9.x86_64/extra/3w-9xxx/3w-9xxx.ko


Additionally I have update the tw_cli and 3DM2 client to their newest versions.

